# South "table _south_new_table already exists"

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

Seems like I have broken all my db, lets hope not
So I have a custom user model in which I have the fields A , B , C , D , E and F
Everytime I try to make a change on the model using schemamigration, it handles this

```
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "_south_new_new_bestjet_users" already exists
```

Also, in my register form, it says that i have and aditional field called H, which doesnt appear on the db model structure, and I have no idea how to delete it because I cant modify the User model through south
Any idea ?
I already tried making fakes migrations , and deleting everything and doing initial ones
So I need more ideas

Comment: Have you tried deleting all of the .pyc files? Are you inheriting from another model that has an `H` field? You might provide your model structure.

Comment: Yes , I delete all of them , and not , its not inheriting anything :/

Comment: Sounds like you might need to restore your database from a backup. You have a backup, right? :)

Comment: I am afraid to said no, but hopefully the page isnt ready yet, so there's no important info on the db yet. So , you mean delete the db and recreate it ?

Comment: Well, if your migrations are failing and your models have fields that aren't there that are showing up, it sounds like you need to start fresh. I'd certainly be running `manage.py validate` to find any obvious problems with your models.